A very faulty Django when it comes to rendering image in my template
Right lets try this again.
My Django images are not showing in my template. Despite setting this up correctly.
This is my setup - a fully replicable setup -, as follows:
# settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')



#urls.py

from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('<uuid:uuid>', views.details),
]

# Only for development. Do not use this in production.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import MediaModule

def details(request, uuid):
    articles  =  MediaModule.objects.all().values()
    article = get_object_or_404(MediaModule, uuid=uuid)
    title = article.article_headline 
    return render(request, 'media-article.html', {'article': article, 'title':title, 'articles':articles})

#media-article.html
 <img src="{{article.article_image.url}}" alt="{{article.article_image.url}}"/>

#models.py
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
class MediaModule(models.Model):
    uuid                   =    models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    article_image          =    models.ImageField(upload_to='static/assets')



This is my file directory layout:


ProjectName-|
  RootFolder-|
    settings.py
  media-| #app name
    templates-|
      media-article.html
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.y
    static-|
       assets-|
         image.jpg



Is there a valid reason as to why, hen I go to the debug console in my browser - does it give me a 404 error despite the src pointing to the correct directory of /static/assets/118118money_u1wgRGw.jpg
Why?!
Yes, I have look at other posts on here before writing this one.
I have literally spend all afternoon on this and now I am seriously looking my patience. I have tried everything, I have added slashed, I have removed slashes, I have changed directories, I have reconfigure directors, I have tried absolutes URl'S, I have tried relative URLS, I have removed the images and readded them, I can confirmed and reconfirmed and reconfirmed and reconfirmed the settings.py, and I have confirmed then again. I have gone into the inspect source code and the URL directory is correct, I go to the director and guess what, error404`, despite the images being in the correct directory and that my configuration is correct.
Everting is correct and I just cannot get these images to show.
I am absolutely livid and I am fuming.

And the image is really there? I mean it is properly downloaded? Try accessing image via direct link from browser. What does django logs say? Is debug mode on?

Yes, the image is there and debug mode is on. Inspecting the source, I get <img src="/media/media/assets/<img.jpg>" alt="/media/media/assets/<img.jpg>">

What about django logs? was there request? was it 404?

Aye, it was a 404. There's no reason why it's a 404 though.

try accesing http://localhost:your_port/media/media/assets/<img.jpg> via browser. Does it work?

wait a minute. I'm starting to see. Your app in project called "media". Are you simplifying your code? because there might be some interesting stuff.

your app called "media". Is there any chance, that you have "/media/" route connected to main urls.py? Beacause seems like you are rewriting "/media/" path to lead to your app, not to media root

let's try a fun stuff. try to acces image via localhost:your_port/media/media/media/assets/<img.jpg> (tripple media)

No and I cant be rewriting anything, the source inspection tells me its in the first direction. I am so fuming with this, and am about to smash this computer.

just try tripple media, if it works - I've got an explanation

if not, I'll need your full file layout. project name, views.py and urls.py from media app dir, views.py and urls.py from project_name_dir (that's inside root dir)

I've changed the directory to media  > static > assets > image.jpg, so now the upload_to is: article_image   =    models.ImageField(upload_to='static/assets')`
Still not working. Shocker there - oh no wait a minutes, its not a shock at all

Its all in the orignal post.

where is settings.py? in "media" folder?

because ye know... if you do django startproject project, django creates a folder, named "project", inside it you have manage.py and a folder "project", containing urls.py, wsgi.py, asgi.py, settings.py

so here's the main question - you include static and media paths in media/urls.py or in root/root/urls.py ? It matters, that's why I ask for full file layout

Right, the directory layout I have updated above. That is the layout of my directory. The media is the app name. So why is Django being a complete utter shit?

where is settings.py file? manage.py? please mention it in layout. It matters.

Aaaaand just tried tripling media, so media/media/media - guess what.....
Is this thing thick or something? Is Django known to be thick?

Please don't delete and repost your question to bypass closure. Your question still lacks a [mre] you haven't shown your urlpatterns to us as I had asked in the previous question as well.

The settings file has been added to the original post.

I mentioned the url patterns (Other than the settings I had mentioned the URLs as well in your previous question), I am guessing the problem is very much as @ZwickVitaly has guessed and you have some url pattern that matches the one for the media URLs.

@AbdulAzizBarkat, thank you for your input - is much appreciated, I saw your comment after I posted my last one and just wanted to acknowledge this I have checked this I I still get the same result.

Hit the URL for the the media file directly in your browser and share the error that you get in the debug page. What URL patterns does it list that it tried? Or does it give  another error?

Your project has this structure
Project-|
    media-| #app
      templates-|
      apps.py
      models.py
      views.py
      urls.y
        media-article.html
      static-|
         assets-|
           image.jpg
    project-| #main app
      settings.py
      urls.py
      asgi.py
      wsgi.py

So you need to delete this from media/urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

and put it in project/urls.py
if you have included paths from media app in urlpatterns here, you better rename path to media app endpoints (to like /media-upload)
